# convert Sql query to LINQ query

Tags: linq

I have written a sql query like

```
DECLARE @OpenDays VARCHAR(15)

SET @OpenDays = (SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(OpenDays,3,LEN(OpenDays)),' - ','')))
     FROM
     (
      SELECT DISTINCT
      STUFF((SELECT ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),SSF.OpenDayOfWeek )
         FROM @FacilityDayOpen SSF
         FOR XML PATH('')
         ), 1, 2, ' ') as OpenDays    
         FROM @FacilityDayOpen S
        ) TS
          )
```

How to convert this query into LINQ

Comment: Not everything is convertible to linq. What you show is typically something to keep in a UDF or otherwise make a linq _equivalent_, like getting the values and do a string.Join in memory.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like a stored procedure I can recommend you use the following program

> http://sqltolinq.com/

but you might want to replace you @values with values you think may work in query and then you so you can check if it working

Comment: Ya  but I am not getting the code for STUFF() and FOR XML PATH()How to convert it into linq.